# Nodejs Tedious Mssql Invalid State

Tags: sql, json, node.js, tedious

I have a virtual box running Ubuntu on my local machine. I have installed nodejs as well as tedious the mssql driver. I'm attempting to pull data from a remote mssql server from a query and return json.

I've read through quite a bit of documentation the first question I would just like answered is do you have to run Nodejs on a windows box to connect to mssql server?

(I am under the impression this is the case when using the standards nodejs windows driver.)

The second question I have stepped through all of my process and the node server is functioning fine but when I get to the mssql call I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid state; requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentLogin7WithStandardLogin state
```

I have not found anyone else that has run into this error with the same situation as myself. I have tried sending the request with the object formation as suggested in this fix.

[How do I connect to SQL Azure from NodeJS/Tedious?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047905/how-do-i-connect-to-sql-azure-from-nodejs-tedious)

I'm still getting the same error as mentioned before. So here is the code. I'm using restify was hoping just to make a restful api our of my nodejs server and spit back json from my mssql calls.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(8080,function(){
  console.log('%s listening at %s',server.name,server.url);
  server.get('/GetInfo',GetInfo);
});

function GetInfo(req, res, next){

  console.log('Starting GetInfo function ...');
  res.header('Content-Type:application/json');

  var config = {
    user:'awesomeusername',
    password:'awesomepassword',
    server:'coolservername',
    options:{
      encrypt:true,
      database:'TableName'
  }
};
var connection = new Connection(config);
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

var sql = "SELECT ColumnName FROM Database.dbo.TableName";
connection.on('connect',function(err){
  request = new Request(sql,function(err,rowCount){
  if(err){
    res.write(err);  
    console.log('got an error %s',err)
  }else{
     res.write(rowCount+'rows'); 
  }
  });

 request.on('row',function(columns){
 columns.forEach(function(column){
 res.write(column.value); 
 });

});

connection.execSql(request);
 });

 }
```

So there you have I'm a complete novice with nodejs I thought I would give it a try. Any tips or information is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) No, you don't have to run code on Windows machine when using Tedious. It's written in pure javascript and should work everywhere nodejs work.

2) First, I would advice you to upgrade to latest Tedious 0.2.x. It's a major release with lots of improvements. Next, I would recomend you to review your code because the snipped you posted has less opening brackets `{` than closing brackets `}`.

Basicly your problem is you're calling `connection.execSql(request);` before the connection was established or regardless if connection was successfull. New Tedious has some improvements in connection error handling, maybe it could help you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.on('connect',function(err){
    request = new Request(sql,function(err,rowCount){
    if(err) {
        res.write(err);  
        console.log('got an error %s',err)
    }
    else {
        res.write(rowCount+'rows'); 
    }
});
```

change above code like below :

```
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    setInterval(()=>{
        console.log("connection.state interval"+JSON.stringify(connection.state));
    },2000);
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("connection.state"+JSON.stringify(connection.state));
        if (connection.state === connection.STATE.LOGGED_IN) {
            executeStatement();// code where connecting query with req and res obj is written.
        }
    },2000);
});

connection.on('debug', function(err) { 
    console.log('debug:', err); // for exception
});
```